# Disable logging except in tests

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, logging

Throughout my app I am using the following logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

However, I want to disable it and disabling logging in general when running tests, so ontop of the `tests.py` file I included:

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

But I would like to be able log test-specific messages. I tried getting a new logger and setting a different level:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('TestLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

But the `disable` call seems to affect it too.

How can I disable all other loggers except for the `logger` I am using in the tests file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logging.disable()` will affect every logger (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.disable).

You could try something like this:

```
import logging
logger1 = logging.getLogger('logger1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('logger2')
keep_this_logger = logging.getLogger('keep_this_logger')

logger1.warning("WARNING 1")
logger2.warning("WARNING 2")
keep_this_logger.warning("WARNING 3")

for key in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict: # gets all loggers
    logging.getLogger(key).disabled = True # disable them 1 by 1

logging.getLogger('keep_this_logger').disabled = False # re-enable your logger

logger1.warning("WARNING 1")
logger2.warning("WARNING 2")
keep_this_logger.warning("YAY!!!") # success
```

EDIT:
Just noticed that you said your main logger is `logging.getLogger()`. This code will only work for named loggers, the root logger doesn't show up in `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict`.